# Natural arithmetic C++ always returns 1

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to implement Natural numbers with C++, here's the code I have so far (O() is the 0 (zero) number and S(Nat) is the successor function).

```
// Peano arithmetic C++
// Null element
struct O{
    explicit operator const unsigned int() const { return 0; }
};

// Successor function    
struct S {
    unsigned int val; 
    explicit operator const unsigned int() const {
        // Boundary check
        std::cout << "Incremented once" << std::endl;
        if (this->val < UINT_MAX) {
            return this->val + 1;
        }
        // Don't wrap around, hit the ceiling and stay there
        return this->val;
    }
    S(const unsigned int a) {
        this->val = a;
    }
    // Constructor
    S(const O& zero) {
        this->val = 0;
    }
    S(const S& s) {
        this->val = static_cast<const unsigned int>(s);
    }
};

// Nat
using Nat = std::variant<O, S>;

int main() {
    std::cout << static_cast<const unsigned int>(S(O())) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<const unsigned int>(S(S(O()))) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I expected was the static_cast to unsigned to give me 1, 2. What I get is actually 1, 1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S(const S& s)` is a copy constructor, and the compiler is allowed to [elide calls](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to the copy constructor in certain cases. This is an optional optimization in C++14 and below, and required in C++17. You can verify that this happens here by putting a print statement inside this constructor, which won't print anything.

In this case, it will make the expression `S(S(O()))` equivalent to `S(O())`.

Therefore, this way of doing things won't work here. You can make `S` a function instead, which can return either an integer (making it trivial), or some object if you prefer to keep things similar to your code here.

Comment: Alright, I think you hit the nail on the head with your explanation. Would it be possible to avoid copy elision if I pass the sum type `Nat` as an argument instead? Changing my constructor to a function here would make the code a bit ugly.

Comment: To anyone still wondering if a variant would trick copy elision: It does not.